# how find the number of conditions in a control structure for a given code segment in java

Tags: java, arrays, count, code-complexity

I want to get the count of conditions a control structure for  a given code segment line by line.Can someone help me to get a correct output?

```
public int[] countCon() {

    char opArray[] ={'<','>','=','!'};

    String[] lines = code.split("\\r?\\n");

    int[] score = new int[lines.length];
    int s = 0;
    score[s] = 0;

    for(String line : lines) {

        String tline = line;

        if(tline.contains("if") || tline.contains("else if") || tline.contains("while") || tline.contains("do") || tline.contains("for") || tline.contains("switch") || tline.contains("case ")){
            if (line.indexOf("if") != -1 ) {
                for(int i = 0;i<=opArray.length-1;i++) {
                    //tline.contains.new String(opArray[i]);
                    opArray[i]++;

                    if(tline.contains("<") || tline.contains(">") || tline.contains("<=") || tline.contains(">=") || tline.contains("==") || tline.contains("!")) {
                        score[s] = score[s]+1;  
                    }
                    else {
                        score[s]=0;
                    }           
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial task since the input provided can be in very different styles. The simplest way is to use regular expressions that match on branching keywords such as `if` (including `else if`), `while`, `for`, etc.. If you are disregarding method calls.

In case you don't want to use regex, your code can be improved too: no need to consider nesting conditions or boolean expressions inside the branching construct. This is because no operators except (tenery `exp ? a : b`) introduces branching.